# Checking an email address exists in the MySQL database without the unique key

Tags: php, mysql, email

So I am a little confused as to how I should do this, at first I tried to lump the username check and email check into one to see if that would work, it would make a check against the username but not against the email.

So I tried separating them out. But here I got confused because I wasn't sure if I could do the same query twice and expect it to work without an error.

I am still new at this, so sorry if this question comes across as "silly" to ask.

Upon submitting I get redirected to my register page which is hitting the second to last if/else statement in the code. "Your passwords do not match..."

Can I use the same kind of query twice for my username, for my email too? Or is there something else that I should have done? I'm just not sure what.

Here is my code for my register.php page:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
  //var_dump($password, $confirmpassword);
  if(strlen($password) > 6 && strlen($password) < 32):

    if($password == $confirmpassword):
      $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = :username');
      $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
      $records->execute();
      $results = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      //var_dump($results);

      if(count($results) > 0):
        echo 'That username is already in use, please use a different one.';

          $emailRecords = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = :email');
          $emailRecords->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
          $emailRecords->execute();
          $emailResults = $emailRecords->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          if(count($emailResults) > 0):
            echo 'That email is already in use, are you sure you\'re not registered with us already? <a href="loginPage.php">Login Here</a>';

      else:

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
        $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $stmt->bindParam(':username',strip_tags($_POST['username']));
        $stmt->bindParam(':password',strip_tags($hashPassword));

        if ($stmt->execute()):
          echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
          header('Location:loginPage.php');
        else:
          echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
          //$message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
        endif;
      endif;

    else:
      echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
      //$message = 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
      header('Location:registerPage.php');
    endif;

  else:
    echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
    //header('Location:registerPage.php');
  endif;

endif;

endif;
?>
```

Comment: **Why** restrict the password length to 32 characters?  Let the user choose 512 characters if they want.

Comment: Well I restricted it, so that the user who logs in doesn't have a hard time trying to remember their password. Of course much later I will hopefully add a "Forgotten Password?" feature.

Comment: Then, to make passwords easier to remember, why not restrict it to 4 characters?

Comment: Well with 4 I think it would be prone to someone's login details being sussed out really easily compared to a longer password which makes it difficult for hackers/crackers to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For the love of everything that is holy, stop using if: else: endif; That's what's messing up your program.

Your individual pieces look ok but your if statements are messed up. Here's what you are doing when nicely styled and formatted with braces:

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    if(strlen($password) > 6 && strlen($password) < 32)
    {
        if($password == $confirmpassword)
        {
            if(count(getUsersWithThisUsername($_POST['username'])) > 0)
            {
                echo 'That username is already in use, please use a different one.';
                if(count(getUsersWithThisEmail($_POST['email'])) > 0)
                {
                    echo 'That email is already in use, are you sure you\'re not registered with us already? <a href="loginPage.php">Login Here</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tryToCreateaUser())
                    {
                        echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
        }
    }
}
```

You can probably figure out yourself that this doesn't make much sense.

Also if you look at this code you'll notice how I've put several parts of it into separate functions (not shown). This is another trick you can use to help you find bugs. By extracting small but complete units of work that you know to be correct into separate functions the rest becomes easier to read.

Here's how the structure should be:

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    if(strlen($password) > 6 && strlen($password) < 32)
    {
        if($password == $confirmpassword)
        {
            if(count(getUsersWithThisUsername($_POST['username'])) > 0)
            {
                echo 'That username is already in use, please use a different one.';
            }
            else
            {
                if(count(getUsersWithThisEmail($_POST['email'])) > 0)
                {
                    echo 'That email is already in use, are you sure you\'re not registered with us already? <a href="loginPage.php">Login Here</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tryToCreateaUser())
                    {
                        echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kempeth, thank you for your input. When you say it doesn't make much sense do you mean in terms of how I have structured it? Because now I see I have an extra closing curly brace?

Comment: @user3453342 You were echoing the wrong messages in the wrong places because you (probably) inserted the new if for the email check incorrectly. That shifted all your echoes one IF further into the structure. Your check if the email exists needs to be in the branch where the username does NOT exist.

Answer (score 0):

We can use exists clause to check if a user exists with given username or email, below is an example:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = :username OR Email = :email
),1,0) AS exists
```

If it returns 1 then, we can say that a user with given username/email already exists. This way, we can check for both username and email in a single query.

Comment: Thank you Darshan, I will be sure to try this out and get back to you.